# How do I create an instant repeater (extend redstone signal without delay) for high frequency clocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I tried the instant repeater from here https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_circuits/Transmission#Instant_repeater but it's too slow for fast clocks.

Comment: What have you tried yourself, apart from installing mods? What speed exactly do you need?

Comment: @Joachim I haven't tried anything else because idk where to begin, I'm not sure how fast it is but I need it to match the observer clock where you have an observer next to a block with a lever on it and redstone surrounding both blocks